# Broke my sudoers password, how do I reset it without using sudo?

Tags: password, sudo, reset

I thought it would be a good idea to finally take the password off my little netbook since it has never actually been of any use, and has mostly just slowed down . But when I went to change my password, there wasn't even an option to make it blank, and any attempt to make it a few easy characters was met with "Password too weak".

So I did what any good geek would do and popped open the terminal, read the manual entry for `passwd` and quickly used the `-d` option to remove the password from my account. It all went well for a couple days (I even managed to also make my keychain password blank) until I tried to update the thing.

My sudoers password is not blank, and it's not my old password. I have no idea what it is. How do I reset it (or even better, make it blank) without the use of the `sudo` command?

Comment: Since the fix is to reset the password (and the problem lies in the password entry itself), this is in effect the same as [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) We should probably close this as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to terminal type `who am i` then type `passwd` and enter the password you want.
You will be able to use that password to change your password on *user accounts*.

Comment: how can he do that from terminal with out sudo ?

Comment: A user can change his own password without sudo.

Answer (score 2):

If you messed up your `sudoers` file, you'll need to:

- Reboot into recovery mode (hit escape during boot, choose the recovery mode option on the grub screen)
- Choose the 'Enable networking' option (if you don't your filesystem will be mounted as read-only. who knew)
- Chosee the 'Drop to root shell' option
- Run `visudo`, fix your file
- Reboot with normal grub option

source :- http://mario.net.au/content/recover-etcsudoers-ubuntu-1204

Answer (score 0):

You can install linux on machine without losing data . only be carefull aboout that use same username . if you want really cracking password i will look for it

Answer (score 0):

After switch on your PC , you will see GRUB menu . In the GRUB menu choose recovery mode and then choose  `root` option  . there type this command

```
passwd
```

Then Give your new password .

then restart.