# My password can log me in, but nothing else ("user is not in the sudoers file" error when I try)

Tags: sudo, user-management

I recently got a new user account for Ubuntu 12.04 on Linux after becoming unable to log in to one of my earlier accounts. I can log in to this account easily enough, but when I try to use the password to install software through the Ubuntu Software Center, it reads:

```
Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again.
```

I tried installing the software through the terminal with this:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

But when I entered my password, I got this message:

```
[username] is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

I searched here for a solution, and I found [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151200/my-main-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file), which told me to open a root terminal. I don't know how to do this, but I found out I could get a root terminal by entering this in a normal terminal:

```
sudo -i
```

Upon doing this, I was asked to enter my `sudo` password, and I got the same message as before. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-in-ubuntu

Comment: @user252617 [You Should Read This](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: @guntbert Not a duplicate. The password is fine (he can login) but he isn't in the sudoers file. Different problem.

Comment: @Seth, no - he hast lost access to the administrative account - the account he has access to isn't one.

Comment: @guntbert Upon rereading it, he is indeed using two accounts. Now the dilemma do  we answer the question he asked or the question that lead him here..

Answer (score 4):

You can boot into recovery mode, start a root shell from there and add your user account to the sudo group with `adduser USERNAME sudo`.

Another solution is, once you are in the root shell, to edit the sudoers file as the thread you linked suggests.

See [Broke my sudoers password, how do I reset it without using sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200757/broke-my-sudoers-password-how-do-i-reset-it-without-using-sudo#228965) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not allowed to execute commands as root user. Be sure your user account is in the group `sudo` (type `id` or `grep $USER /etc/group` to find out).

If it is not, you have to get it in there. Try to launch your system in recovery mode, you should be able to access a single user root shell from there. Then you can type `adduser your_username sudo`. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Log in as either root or a user that does have sudo access, then type: `visudo` and add the user you're having trouble with to the sudoers file.